# Create new files in Shell script using VIM

Tags: bash, shell-script, vim

I am writing a script to automate few steps and need to create new configuration files with predefined location and text.

I am able to create the files however i am not sure how i can enter the text and save the files automatically using VIM.

**Example**:

Create a configuration file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/cgi-enabled.conf` with the following text

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/cgi-enabled">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
</Directory>
```

and save it, this would allow me to move on to next configuration file. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is from a shell script I would recommend forgoing vim altogether and instead using echo, ie `echo "sample text" > file.cfg` this will create your file and fill it with the necessary content.

Comment: Aah! I was over-complexing things. Thank you! Will try this out.

Answer (score 3):

No need to start `vim`, just use a here-document:

```
cat >/etc/httpd/conf.d/cgi-enabled.conf <<END_CONF
<Directory "/var/www/html/cgi-enabled">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
</Directory>
END_CONF
```

The text between `<<END_CONF` and the last `END_CONF` delimiter will be saved to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/cgi-enabled.conf` through redirection by `cat`. The choice of delimiter is arbitrary, but one usually uses an uppercase word.

If you have shell variables (or things that looks like shell variables) in the here-document and you *don't* want these replace by their values, you should single-quote the first `END_CONF`:

```
cat >/etc/httpd/conf.d/cgi-enabled.conf <<'END_CONF'
<Directory "/var/www/html/cgi-enabled">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
</Directory>

<!-- $HOME will not be expanded here -->
END_CONF
```